# How to update table after a certain time interval

Tags: mysql

How can I update a table after some time interval when a condtion is matched?

```
tb_contest
id   contest_id   name   is_expire
1    101          new    0
2    102          old    0

tb_answer
contest_id   answer_id   date
101          1           2012-02-02
101          2           2012-09-14
102          5           2012-06-01
```

I need to update `tb_contest` after some condition was met and make `is_expire=1` after 2 days on basis of the last answer received i:e `2012-03-14`, so the `tb_contest` should be updated on `2012-09-16`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one,

```
UPDATE tb_contest a INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT contest_ID, MAX(`date`) maxDate
            FROM tb_answer
            GROUP BY contest_ID
        ) b ON a.contest_ID = b.contest_ID
SET a.is_expire = 1
WHERE   DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), b.maxDate) >= 2 AND 
        a.is_expire = 0
```

So here it goes, the two tables were joined by `contest_ID` and having the lastest answered date on `tb_answer`. By using `DATEDIFF()` we can know the difference between  today's date and the date the contest has been answered.

Answer (score 6):

You could use MySQL's [event scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/events.html):

```
CREATE EVENT expire_contests
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY DAY
     STARTS CURRENT_DATE
  DO UPDATE tb_contest JOIN (
       SELECT   contest_id, MAX(date) AS latest
       FROM     tb_answer
       GROUP BY contest_id
     ) t USING (contest_id)
     SET    tb_contest.is_expire = 1
     WHERE  tb_contest.is_expire <> 1
        AND t.latest <= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 DAY
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `JOIN` the contest and an inner-query on the answer table in the `UPDATE` clause and use MySQL's [`DATEDIFF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) to count the number-of-days since the answer was, well, answered:

```
UPDATE
    tb_contest c
    JOIN (SELECT contest_id, MAX(date) AS date FROM tb_answer GROUP BY contest_id) AS a
        ON a.contest_id = c.id
SET
    c.is_expire = 1

WHERE 
    DATEDIFF(NOW(), a.date) >= 2
```

Comment: What if I have to do the same for contest_id=102 which has also multiple entry

Comment: @Mdharmendra The query in my answer will update any/all contests that have a "last answer" of 2-or-more days ago; if you want to specify an exact contest, you can change the `WHERE` clause to `WHERE c.id = 102 AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), a.date) >= 2`