# cron job to automate csv upload to update database

Tags: php, sql, csv

Is there a way to make a cron job, or another way to automate uploading a CSV file to update prices in a database?

Currently, I use Sequel Pro to upload a file when I am running a sale on an e-com site. It's a simple CSV file with product id and price that I use to update the table in Sequel Pro.

Just wondering if there is a way to automate that so I don't have to stay up or be at a computer at the time of the start of the sale.

I know I can make a cron job to run a PHP file, but I'm not sure an easy way to copy the CSV file to the PHP update statement.

Answer (score 1):

For your problem, you may use [MSQL Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html)
Where you can use a query like this which one will help to update your value after a certain time

```
CREATE EVENT expire_contests
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY DAY
     STARTS CURRENT_DATE
  DO UPDATE tb_contest JOIN (
       SELECT   contest_id, MAX(date) AS latest
       FROM     tb_answer
       GROUP BY contest_id
     ) t USING (contest_id)
     SET    tb_contest.is_expire = 1
     WHERE  tb_contest.is_expire <> 1
        AND t.latest <= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 DAY
```

For more, you may visit this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421756/how-to-update-table-after-a-certain-time-interval)